# Find the 'best' longest common subsequence

Tags: dynamic-programming, strings, graph-traversal, string-matching

I am writing a program that computes and displays diffs. I implemented [Meyers algorithm](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) that computes the LCS between 2 subsequences (`seq1` and `seq2`); its output is one of the possible LCS and a partition of `seq1` and `seq2`, one projection of which is `lcs`.

I want to improve it so that the LCS displayed minimizes the number of breaks; to do so, I implemented a function `f(lcs, seq)`:

- `seq` is a sequence of characters
- `lcs` is a subsequence of `seq`
- the output is a partition of `seq` `p0, p1, p2, ... pn` such as

  - either `p0 + p2 +`  or `p1 + p3 + ...` is `lcs`
  - and `n` is minimal

I did so using some sort of BFS, at each step finding the next element non-covered in `lcs` in `seq` and greedily expanding the common part.

The resulting algorithm is quite slow: on a typical input, ~3x slower that the Myers algorithm which seems to compute something way more complex.  See code here: https://github.com/mookid/diffr/blob/c9ed7746193fd9833ddce1237d6e5005e91deaf4/diffr-lib/src/best_projection.rs

Am I missing a better algorithm?

Comment: One way to do this is by using Gotoh's sequence alignment algorithm to compute affine gap costs -- this is where you pay an extra cost for opening a new gap (vs. extending an existing gap). But this takes $\Theta(nm)$ time and memory. Myers's algorithm takes $O(nd)$ time which is quadratic too, but usually $d \ll n$ (or the diff would be unhelpful) so it's much faster, and it can also work with just $O(n)$ memory. [This page](https://seqan.readthedocs.io/en/master/Tutorial/Algorithms/Alignment/PairwiseSequenceAlignment.html) gives more details.

Comment: BTW, any greedy approach is likely to get stuck. E.g. if `seq1 = "RED.APPLEREDAPPLE.R.E.D"` and `lcs = "REDAPPLERED"`, an approach that tries to make the longest initial unbroken match will produce `"red.appleREDAPPLE.R.E.D"` (positions matched to `lcs` are capitalised) with 3 breaks instead of `"RED.APPLEREDapple.r.e.d"` with just 1 break.

Comment: thanks for the pointer! I will have a look.  Here greediness means that once I match lcs[0] = R with seq1[0], i keep matching E = seq1[1] rather than trying to match E at some later index.

Comment: You're welcome :) I believe Myers's algorithm is already greedy in the way you describe -- it always tries to extend "snakes" as far as they can go.

Comment: Another approach that I would recommend (a variant of which is used by the DNA sequence alignment tool MUMmer to great effect) is to look for a maximum-length unique match (MUM) between `seq1` and `lcs` -- that is, the longest substring that appears in both strings exactly once. This can be found in $O(n)$ time and space with a generalised suffix tree. This leaves you with 2 smaller subproblems to solve, one on each "side" of the MUM. Requires some careful programming if you need to implement the suffix tree yourself, but should be fast in practice.

Comment: This may fail to find the best global solution: consider "abc.ef.abcd.e.f" and "abcef" (notice there that the ordering issue). But it's a nice way to get a good partial solution.

Comment: also note that in my particular case, the alphabet is effectively infinite (I am doing word-based diff, so the alphabet is a set of words). So this limits my possibilities, I am not sure suffix trees are applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Your applications may be different from mine, but I think want you want is to input two strings $a$ and $b$ and output a diff $d$ such that no diff is shorter than $d$ and no *shortest* diff has fewer breaks than $d$. By a diff I mean the algebraic data type `List of ((CommonToBoth | FromLeftString | FromRightString) * Char)`, best expressed in Rust as a sequence of a three-variant Enum, each storing a character (or a `T`, if generic).  Minimizing breaks amounts roughly minimizing the number of runs of `CommonToBoth`. [Concretely I call mine `Common`, `Insert` and `Delete`.]

I'm not sure that computing a break-minimizing matching $m_a$ between $d$ and $a$ and a break-minimizing matching $m_b$ between $d$ and $b$ will let you compute a break-minimizing matching $m_{ab} = g(m_a, m_b)$ between $d$ and [$a$ and $b$ simultaneously], which is the thing I think you really want.

I've managed to compute a shortest diff with the smallest number of breaks, using an adaptation of [Wagner-Fischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm) (dynamic programming, $O(n^2)$ space for a big table).

Normally you store the LCS length in the Wagner-Fischer table. Instead of doing that, you can choose a score of your own and store it instead.  I've used triples similar to `(lcsLength, numberOfBreaks, isCurrentRunSharedOrEdits)`. There's a trick: when characters don't match you need to do something more complicated than `max`, and when they do it's not always dominant to include the particular match you're looking at: table entry `(i, j)` is the best among `adjustScoreInMatchingCase(table[i-1, j-1])` and `combineMismatchingScore(table[i-1, j], table[i, j-1])`, where the two functions depend on the particulars of how you score things.

This works, but takes $O(n^2)$ time and space.  I can't do much about asymptotic time (provably so if the exponential time hypothesis is true, IINM). I think you can improve the space requirements by only storing the previous and current row of the table; you don't refer back more than a single row in the Wagner-Fischer algorithm.

Incidentally, I think the logic in the Myers algorithm which cleverly constructs and (re)uses the `v` array doesn't work in this case; the fact that if `a[i] == b[j]` you don't always extend from `LCS(a[..i-1], b[..j-1])` is rooted in the reason why we can't trivially extend the `v` array. But I might be wrong, I haven't fully explored the problem.

Postscript: Unless smake is a new build tool I haven't heard about, you probably want to rename `max_sMake_len` ($m \rightarrow n$). If you like property testing you may want to steal my tests at https://github.com/jonaskoelker/equate/blob/master/test/EquateProperties.scala; but beware, one or two of them have slightly wrong labels.